# JTextfield Addition through program

Tags: java, swing

I have 3 JText fields in my form. First two fields for getting mark1 and mark2,  finally one for displaying the sum of the mark1 and mark2.

The problem is when I enter a value in mark1 it should be displayed in the total field. Also when I enter mark2 value the mark1 value plus mark2 field value will need to be added immediately to the total field using java code?

Note I don't want to use a button to compute the sum.

Comment: **Note dont use a button to add**  Sure thing.  BTW - did you have a question, any code, any ..attempt at doing your own work before hoping that someone else would do it for you?  SO is not a code generation factory.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example.

[image]

```
package sof;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
    JTextField text3 = new JTextField();

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        CustomDocListener cd = new CustomDocListener();

        text1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(cd);
        text2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(cd);

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        pnl.add(text1);
        pnl.add(text2);
        pnl.add(text3);
        this.add(pnl);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomDocListener implements DocumentListener{
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            fireChange();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            fireChange();
        }

        private void fireChange(){
            int value1 = 0, value2 = 0;
            try {
                value1 = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                value1 = 0;
            }
            try {
                value2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                value2 = 0;
            }
            text3.setText(value1 + value2 + "");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: -1, for using a KeyListener. If you want to know when the contents of a text component change you should be using a DocumentListener. A KeyListener would be used with AWT. Swing has newer and better classes to use like DocumentListener, DocumentFilter and the concept of Key Bindings.

Comment: @camickr : Thanks for the input, have modified my answer.

Comment: Again, as a general rule, a DocumentFilter would be preferred over a customized Document. I know in this case it doesn't really matter, but a DocumentFilter can be added to any Document, so potentially the same filter could be used with a JTextField, JTextArea, JEditorPane, JTextPane. The purpose of a DocumentFilter is to filter the input before it is added to the Document. You have basically reinvented the wheel by using a custom Document to provide the same functionality.

Comment: You also need to handle removeUpdate() and the DocumentListner can be shared.